# Navigate to the same route from different paths in Angular

Tags: angular, localization

I guess I don't understand how route matcher works..
Anybody can help me?
How I can do something like this:

```
{
  path: '' || 'ru' || 'en' || 'pl'
  component: SomeComponent,
  canActivate: [ActivateGuard],
  children: []
}
```

I try this:

```
{
  matcher: matcher,
  component: SomeComponent,
  canActivate: [ActivateGuard],
  children: []
}

function matcher(segment) {
  if (segments[0]?.path === 'ru' || segments[0]?.path === 'en' || segments[0]?.path === 'pl') {
    return {consumed: segments};
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `redirectTo` and do something like this:

```
{
  path: 'some'
  component: SomeComponent,
  canActivate: [ActivateGuard],
  children: []
},
{
    path: '', redirectTo: 'some', pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'ru', redirectTo: 'some', pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'en', redirectTo: 'some', pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'pl', redirectTo: 'some', pathMatch: 'full'
}
```